# MATLAB: Calling a M file from another M file

Tags: function, matlab

Sorry this is such a basic question, but I can't find a straight answer and it doesn't seem to have been answered on here before (perhaps because it is so basic?!)

I'm trying to call a M function from within another M file. The function I am calling is a primary function and has no inputs or outputs: it is simply some lines of code that I'd like to insert many times in my main M-file.

The function is called

```
function generateGrating
```

and resides in the file generateGrating.m. The main function is called

```
function project
```

and resides in the file project.m. As you can see, there is no input or output in either. They simply run their routines.

I have tried the following to attempt to call the function, with no luck:

```
generateGrating()
generateGrating
generateGrating.m()
generateGrating.m
generateGrating();
generateGrating;
generateGrating.m();
generateGrating.m;
```

Any help would be appreciated! It seems that the answer must be so basic that I can't find it anywhere :(

Comment: Works for me when calling `generateGrating`. Maybe there is a spelling error somewhere in the names or the file `generateGrating.m` is not found by Matlab. Are both files in the same directory?

Comment: Thanks. The issue was actually that the second routine wouldn't run because it required variables defined in the first. I hadn't realised that functions have private variables in MATLAB. Kind of makes sense really, being based on C :S

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that you want to use a **script, not a function**.

A script is a .m file **without the keyword function** at the beginning.

So for instance, i fI have two files:

sub.m:

```
b=b+1;
```

main.m:

```
function main
  b=1;
  b
  sub;
  b
  sub;
  b
```

I get the answer:

```
b=1
b=2
b=3
```

If I change sub.m to make it a function:

sub.m:

```
function sub
  b=b+1;
```

The variable b inside sub is now from **a different scope** than b in main.m
So I get the answer:

```
b=1
b=1
b=1
```

Answer (score 1):

It should just be `generateGrating`.  The files `generateGrating.m` and `project.m` need to both be in directories that are included in the Matlab path.  The easiest way to accomplish that is to have them both be in the same directory and to run with that directory as your working directory.  The simplest thing to do is to open `project.m` and hit F5 to run it, and click the "Change directory" button if it pops up.

**NOTE**

If `generateGrating` is populating some variables (it sounds like that's what you're doing), then DON'T make `generateGrating` a `function`.  Otherwise any variables that are set in `generateGrating.m` will only be in scope within that function.  For example:

```
% generateGrating.m
function generateGrating()
x = 42;

% project.m
x = 1;
generateGrating
disp(x)
```

Will display x = 1 because x is only 42 within the scope of the function `generateGrating`.  But changing `generateGrating.m` to

```
% generateGrating.m
x = 42;
```

And running `project` again will display x = 42;